# Php. Перевод байт в число

Tags: php, байты

Имеется массив байт

```
$a = Array
(
    [0] => f4
    [1] => 77
    [2] => 95
    [3] => 59
);
```

Пробую собрать их в число

```
$time = unpack('V', '\xf4\x77\x95\x59');
```

На выходе получаю 879130716, хотя должно быть 1502967796. Пробовал разные параметры, везде не правильный. Порядок порядок little endian.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$a = array(0xf4, 0x77, 0x95, 0x59);
$i = ($a[3] << 24) + ($a[2] << 16) + ($a[1] << 8) + $a[0];
echo $i;
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/65016d0fa06eed644aac5e0fa5e1889591c793d0